# the onclick event listener does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add an event listener inside of a class. No matter how I instantiate the function onclick, it doesn't work. The process is the same and work's outside of the class without the this. reference. But does not work with the this. reference inside of the class. The problem is not just adding a reference function. It was the correct approach to adding a reference function inside of a class. Which was answered. Use es6 arrow function to automatically bind.

```
class MultiPage {
      //constructor is used to initialize state and events
      constructor() {
        this.purchaseButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
        this.itemId = document.getElementsByClassName("itemId");
        this.description = document.getElementsByClassName("description");
        this.price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
        this.quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");
        this.type = document.getElementsByClassName("type"); //outer set loop through inner elemnts
        this.pushProductOption = [];
        this.photo = document.getElementsByClassName("photoSet"); //outer set loop through inner elemnts
        this.pushPhotoSet = [];
        this.cart = document.getElementsByClassName("cart")[0];
        this.setEventListeners();
      }
    
      setEventListeners() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.purchaseButton.length; i++) {
          this.purchaseButton[i].addEventListener(
            "click",
            this.addToCart(
              this.purchaseButton[i],
              this.itemId[i].innerHTML,
              this.description[i].innerHTML,
              this.photo[i].src,
              this.price[i].innerHTML,
              1,
              this.type[i].value
            )
          );
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you share  related html code too in snippet.

Comment: You need to move this logic from constructor to `componentDidMount`, there is a chance that your elements don't exist in DOM if they are rendered in this Component

Comment: You're calling `this.addToCart` instead of passing a function. Maybe changing to `() => this.addToCart` would work?

Comment: @evolutionxbox can't use arrow function but the on the problem I admit with you

Comment: @Gad, what do you mean *"can't use arrow function"*? Of course you can (and should)

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: @trincot because arrow function doesn't support `this` key word

Comment: @Gad it does? However, it doesn't rebind `this`. This is something you don't want anyway.

Comment: @Gad, it supports the `this` keyword, and it is exactly what is needed here, as it will refer to the `this` of the `setEventListeners` execution context. Using a `function` here would actually get a different `this` value, which is not what this code needs.

Comment: @trincot yeah thats right. function didnt work for the longest time and was wondering why

Comment: Blatantly not related to the link shown `This question already has answers here: `

Answer (score 1):

```
this.purchaseButton[i].addEventListener("click", () =>
    this.addToCart(
        this.purchaseButton[i],
        this.itemId[i].innerHTML,
        this.description[i].innerHTML,
        this.photo[i].src,
        this.price[i].innerHTML,
        1,
        this.type[i].value
    )
);
```

You should give a function as the second argument, I hope wrapping it with an arrow function solves the problem.

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score -1):

this should get you started.  when you use e6 this gets binded automatically.  Here's how to do it the old way.

```js
class MultiPage {
      //constructor is used to initialize state and events
      constructor() {
        this.purchaseButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
      //  console.log(this.purchaseButton);
        this.itemId = document.getElementsByClassName("itemId");
        this.description = document.getElementsByClassName("description");
        this.price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
        this.quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");
        this.type = document.getElementsByClassName("type"); //outer set loop through inner elemnts
        this.pushProductOption = [];
        this.photo = document.getElementsByClassName("photoSet"); //outer set loop through inner elemnts
        //console.log(this.photo[0].src);
        this.pushPhotoSet = [];
        this.cart = document.getElementsByClassName("cart");
        this.setEventListeners();
      }
    
      setEventListeners() {
      
      //console.log(this);
      
     
        for (let i = 0; i < this.purchaseButton.length; i++) {
        this.purchaseButton[i].addEventListener("click", function addToCart()
    {console.log('inside= ',this);
        this.purchaseButton[i],
        console.log(this.purchaseButton[i]);
        this.itemId[i].innerHTML,
        this.description[i].innerHTML,
       this.photo[i].src,
       this.price[i].innerHTML,
        1,
        this.type[i].value
        
        
    }.bind(this)
);
        
        }
      }
}

var myObj = new MultiPage();

console.log(myObj.purchaseButton[0]);
```

```html
<div class='button itemId description price quantity type cart'>xxx</div>

<img  class='photoSet' src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
```

Comment: Why would you give a bad answer then a good one